# Grails GORM + Mongo, How to save custom data to id?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

Try to save something custom in id field in Grails:

```
Cover saveCover = new Cover(id: url, url: url, name: name, sku: sku, price: price)
```

But in DB I see that in _id field something like this: 52658d9284aea229e226ab9c. It confuse me, cause it looks like ObjectId, but not string that I send to Cover domain (by the way in Cover domain field id is String).

What`s wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

That is the ObjectID that MongoDb generates automatically for you. 
See : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

> "MongoDB uses ObjectIds as the default value for the _id field if the
>   _id field is not specified. MongoDB clients should add an _id field with a unique ObjectId. However, if a client does not add an _id
>   field, mongod will add an _id field that holds an ObjectId."

if you want to set your own id , set "_id" instead of "id"

Comment: This doesn`t work, I have mark my field as index with uniq value to maintain such behavier on DB level.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a custom assigned id instead of the generated id you need to set a mapping.

```
class Cover {
    String id
    String name
    String url
    String sku
    String price
    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PaddyDwyer is right but I think the answer is not complete. After several efforts, I found also that it is important to use *insert* and not *save* for each new object in which you make id manual assignment (see official [GRAILS_Mongo Doc](http://gorm.grails.org/mongodb/manual/guide/single.html) at 3.1), as below:

```
Cover c = new Cover()
c.id = "custom_id"
c.name = "new name"
c.insert()
```

Of course all the ids assigned have to be all different.